# 5V regulator circuit with MOSFET. Will this catch on fire?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I have a circuit that takes a 5V output from a USB bank with 10000mAh and supplies MOSFET1, whose drain (5Vgreeni) then goes through a fuse to a 5V regulator circuit.

I don't have any heat sinks or fans.  The power supply needs a capacity of 2amperes but will most likely regularly consume about 700mA.

Based on this I don't think my MOSFET1 (FQP47P06) needs active cooling or a heatsink, but there is another MOSFET in the circuit that is a bit smaller and I am not so sure about it.  With the ambient temperature in the box exceeding 100F at times I am concerned that this may be a fire hazard.

Should I be concerned about DMG2305UX-7?

[image: circuit]

Edit here is another diagram of the circuit:

[image: circuit2]

Comment: is BCM857BS115 just two transistors on a chip? if so, I don't understand the transistor circuit, and it should be drawn with two transistor symbols instead of a chip symbol.

Comment: If the input voltage is a regulated 5 V, the output of this circuit (if it works) will be somewhat less than 5 V.

Comment: see edit, added a better diagram.  Is there a way to compensate for the drop in voltage caused by the circuit?

Comment: Most of the drop should be caused by the fuse. But what is the purpose of this circuit? To protect against the USB port being wired with the wrong polarity? Also FQP47P06 will not conduct with 5V Vgs, you need a logic level FET.

Comment: The purpose is I am trying to tie the 5V output directly into a raspberry pi 5V header, which bypasses its circuit protection.  I didn't know if the USB banks output would give me a stable 5V so I am trying to replicate some of the circuit protection that the Pi had built in.

Comment: Where is your link to the datasheet and power dissipation calculations?  This is logically just an ideal diode on the 5V side with Ohmic losses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ron=52 mOhm @ 4.5V seems appropriate until you compute load current of whatever you are applying.

Consider Pd*Rjc \$=\Delta T\$ rise (23’C/W = Rjc) for a SOT-23 as the temp. risk of burning your finger. Compute and then You decide if it exceeds 55’C on the case to your finger.

Fire is unlikely.

\$\Delta T_{case}= I^2 * 52 m\Omega * 23 ‘C/W\$

But you chose the wrong FET type instead of a logic level type with Vgs(th)=-0.9V MAX, you chose an old standard threshold TO-220 FET with 4V max threshold @ -250uA

So instead of 25mOhms you are not in full conduction yet and it appears from the plots that with a 10% drop in Vds from 5 or 0.5V at some high current like 2.4A or 12W this FET will be drawing constant (ish) current vs Vds meaning 10% of the sourced power is wasted in the FET and 1.2W with a thermal resistance from junction to ambient of almost 100’C (epoxy is an insulator) your junction temp is 120’c above ambient of 25’C or exceeding spec or “burning up electrons of material” thus satisfying the Darwinian Arhennius Law of reduced MTBF. So you need a 2 to 4W heatsink.

Next time choose a “Logic Level FET”

It won’t burn your finger but the junction is saying ouch at max power right now.

Comment: I am confused, are you referring to the DMG2305 MOSFET?  And are saying I could drop in a logic level FET and not need a heatsink?  Not that your answer was unclear, I just am somewhat unfamiliar.

Comment: Yes a logic level FET would not heat a heatsink is what I said. But your choice does!

Comment: Because logic level FETs are relatively new in the last 2 decades, they are mostly SMT.

Comment: Vgs needs to be >= 3x Vgs(th) so > 9 and better with 10 or 12V on 4V max threshold, sub-1V threshold types need a minimum of 2x for Vgs(th) to conduct well and slightlymore is better.

Comment: Would NDS356AP or FDWS9511L-F085 be what you are suggesting?  For LL MOSFET P-Ch

Comment: ended up going with FDWS9511L-F085